# Azure AD Graph API: Is it possible to enumerate all groups associated with an application role?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to enumerate all users and/or groups associated with an application role using Azure Active Directory Graph API? If not, is there a programmatic work-around (as opposed to using the portal with AD Premium)?

I'm using the `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` Nuget package which wraps the AD Graph API to fetch application roles associated with an application instance. Unfortunately the `AppRole` object doesn't include a method to fetch mapped principals.

Comment: Also the `AppRoleAssignments` property of the `Group` object apparently doesn't provide this data either.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the service principal that is associated with an application role, you can query for all the objects associated with that service principal (which include all the app roles):

https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/servicePrincipals/#objectId#/appRoleAssignedTo?api-version=1.5

The documentation for app role assignments are here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#AppRoleAssignmentEntity